# Extract Working/Non-Working Hours With Weekend/Weekday Breakdown For A Working Schedule

Tags: php, datetime

I do need a calculation script for my project which would be calculating 4 things in minutes for me.

- Total assigned minutes in working hours for weekdays (Between 08.30 - 17.30)
- Total assigned minutes in out of working hours for weekdays (Except 08.30 - 17.30)
- Total assigned minutes in working hours for weekends (Between 08.30 - 17.30)
- Total assigned minutes in out of working hours for weekends (Except 08.30 - 17.30)

Basically, I am creating and using a schedule *Google Calendar actually but doesnt matter, I just have start-end datetime objects in my hand* for the employees on a calendar and assigning datetime ranges to employees to make them responsible for answering the customer calls in a certain time range which also could last a week, a few hours, a few minutes or a few days. The thing here is those date ranges are pretty flexible.

I've tried looping over the unix timestamp, creating a DateTime object per loop and check those 4 things but that would have been too much memory&cpu usage as I locked my computer a few times. I would be able to loop over hours in day if the events could only last a day at maximum but they are very flexible so I need a strong algorithm here.

For example a schedule would look like below:

```
Start(DateTime Object) => 2022-01-27 00:00:00
End(DateTime Object)   => 2022-01-29 13:30:00
```

The function should take those two objects as an argument and should create an output like in the picture I ve shared below. Should be similiar to this:

```
function createReport(DateTime $employeeWorkStart, DateTime $employeeWorkEnd) : array {
...
return [
    'weekday_in-working-hours' => XXX,
    'weekday_out-working-hours' => XXX,
    'weekend_in-working-hours' => XXX,
    'weekday_out-working-hours' => XXX,
]
```

}

So I need to create a monthly-basis report which shows how many minutes I've assigned for each employee in the schedule.

My working hours are between 08.30 - 17.30, saturday & sunday is considered as weekend.
[Example Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcfVV.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: As I've shared in the description, I tried looping the unix timestamp integer (knew it wasnt gonna be possible but just wanted to see). Also tried looping the hours of a day for each schedule but then found out an event could last longer than a day and stopped that idea. All the other approaches got stuck and I lost track to follow the script.

Answer (score 0):

So, not able to provide an actual code-answer right now. But how I would approach it is the following:

- Get the amount of days between the two dates, subtract weekends. Also subtract one day if the $employeeWorkEnd is the current day (today) and if you want to have extra precision. I found this gist that gives you the working days (weekends and holidays excluded): https://gist.github.com/quawn/8503445
- Multiply this by 9 (working hours) and then by 60 to get the total minutes. This is the total time worked.
- If you wanted the extra precision in step 1, now just take the difference in minutes between 09:30 and the current time (`date_diff` can provide this). Add this difference to the total you had so far.

Execute this procedure for every employee you have. The above procedure will not do any loops, I believe it should be possible to do it just by subtraction and multiplication (if you want to exclude holidays using the code in the gist, this will introduce a small loop assuming low amount of holidays).

Your example output shows hours but your description shows minutes. The above story will give you minutes but it's just as easy to get the hours (or milliseconds for that matter).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, approaches are also well appreciated. But the thing is this doesn't feel like we are also calculating it right. Employee might not have been scheduled for the all working hours in a day or am I missing something?
Edit: Holidays are fine, i am not taking them into consideration.

Comment: Ah, this was not clear to me. So an employee has a flexible working hours per day? If you are providing a start datetime and an end datetime as the only parameters it's impossible to make this calculation. Can you amend your question to include this and show the data you have available to show the employee worked x hours on the day?

Comment: Just to make it more clear, I create events in Google Calendar and assign an employee to that event. When a customer fills a form in my website, I assign the customer to the right employee by checking who is assigned for that datetime range. So, events could last an hour, last a day or longer than a day or even 15 minutes. There are no specific slots like 1 hours or 30 mins. For example an event could start last week and can go to next week thursday, lets say 13.30. I hope that explains it

Comment: Alright, I'm getting closer to what you're trying to do. So if you map your parameters to the Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list#php), this would be the "timeMin" and "timeMax" parameters? In that case shouldn't you just loop through all relevant events and take the difference between timeMin and timeMax to get the full length. You can look at the time hours and minutes to determine whether it was out of working hours or not, and you can use the days to determine whether it was in the weekend or not. Am I getting warm or still not quite there yet?

Comment: No. I shared Google thing just for the clarity. Just think that you have start-end datetimes. Google Calendar can't help us here, I am only using it to fetch those start-end datetimes and creating an array. As i mentioned before, events are not strictly a day or two, three etc. They are flexible by the minutes. An employee could start at Wednesday 09.30 and can end 2 weeks after Thursday 15.00.

Comment: Okay, and what happens if you have a datetime range spanning over multiple days? You count the full days as 9 hours to be classified as within working time and the rest of the 24 hours as overtime?

Comment: whatever is between working hours should be counted as working-hours. except them, every minute should be considered out of working hours. Lets say an employee starts today at 07.30 and ends tomorrow at 12.30. Because he started one hour earlier (8.30 is start of working) we should add 1 hour from there. He works all day until 17.30 so its 9 hours from there too. Now we should also count the time between 17.30 in evening and 08.30 next morning as out-of-working-hours. Then he also works for 4 hours (8.30 to 12.30). That should be considered in-working-hours.